# Protractor async/await for non-angular

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, async-await, protractor

I am trying to transfer my tests for a non-Angular website into [async/await](https://www.protractortest.org/#/async-await) control flow. Some tests are OK, but some have problems.

I am trying to log in and wait until the element is clickable, I tried usual construction for loading the element:

```
        browser.wait(EC.urlIs(browser.baseUrl + url.home), 7000, 'url is not as expected');
```

The same for element:

```
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(dashpage.creds), 7000, 'element card holder is not visible');
```

But the test fails here with a notification.

I tried also construction like:

```
        expect(await browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain(url.home);
```

But this expectation always fails.

This is code sample:

```
beforeAll(async function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    await browser.get(browser.baseUrl);

});
it('Log in as a new user and buy credits from member profile', async function () {
    email = hel.randomEmail();
    console.log(email);
    await homeact.fill_signup_form(par.male_name, email, par.password, par.canada, 0);
    await homeact.signup_submit();
    browser.wait(EC.urlIs(browser.baseUrl + url.home), 7000, 'url is not as expected');
    //expect(await browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain(url.home);
    await dashact.check_creds(0);
    await dashact.to_cred_popup();
    //check closing pop-up:
    await buycract.close_popup();
```

Please, help me to apply delay for conditions code.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: try disable selenium promises in protractor config file. SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,

Comment: This is done, sorry, haven't written this 
    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,

 // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
 jasmineNodeOpts : {
  defaultTimeoutInterval : 9999000
 },

Comment: i could not understand what you mean! Can you be more specific if the answer was correct or still have the issue.

Comment: Ok. The issue still exists. I added as recommended the param SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER to my conf.js file. In spec I use page object model. I go to main page and log in. After success I try to check url. I tried both constructions browser.wait and expect(await ...). But in first case with browser.wait protracted test passed, but notification is displayed, that "url is not as expected". The same is for intractable elements. Browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable...) tests passed but in log again timeout error. Construction expect(await) always fails in case of awaiting dom changes or url changes.

Comment: can you give code example

Comment: Sure. As you see in spec sample in topic post, I go to landing page and sign up as a new user. After this redirection to url happens. This code: browser.wait(EC.urlIs(browser.baseUrl + url.home), 7000, 'url is not as expected'); gives in log:  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError Wait timed out after 15125ms: If I try construcrtion with jasmine expectation that is commented below, I receive error that url is still old. So, how can I check that user really is redirected to proper url? Thanks

Comment: I think `ignoreSynchronization` is deprecated. Try using `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` instead. Then the 15 sec-timeout indicates, that your problem is most probably not in the `browser.wait()`, that you listed (they have 7 sec). Could the problem be in `browser.get(browser.baseUrl)`? Try making this a first test case instead of a beforeAll OR use the possibility of setting the baseUrl in `conf.js`

Comment: This, browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false) does not work either. Also with browser.get(browser.baseUrl) everything is ok. The same happens in other specs for browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable...) that previously worked

Comment: You need to await `browser.wait()` also. so `await browser.wait(EC.urlIs( // ... ))` Have you tried moving the await to the front of your assertion like this: `await expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain(url.home)`?

Comment: Sorry, nothing helps for this spec, only timeout. But thanks and the latest await browser.wait works for elements to be intractable.

Answer (score 0):

```
await browser.wait(EC.urlIs(browser.baseUrl + url.home), 7000, 'url is not as expected');
```

This should then work:

```
expect(await browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain(url.home);
```

I have made a change of regular e2e to async and came across that for simple page objects making each function async and put await in each call of this function. It works but complex; PO is a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

try `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);` it will disable the waiting and eventually solve your problem. This is bad practice for an angular application and should be avoided.